# Multiple Y and Multiple X regression

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to solve a problem. A production plant has an extensive data set on 20 inputs (independent variable, feedstock and process conditions) and 6 outputs (dependent variables, production yield). We are trying to find out the relationship between the 20 inputs and 6 outputs, and also apply some constraints to the model (e.g. the sum of outputs must not exceed 100%).

I am still a learner of Python. May I ask what type of problem is this and how can it be analysed using Python? I've been searching for answers online, seems like it might be a kind of "multivariate regression", but I am not sure.

Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: Are you trying to find out the general equation, or just need a way to illustrate data within that domain of 20 points meanwhile  be able to calculate any y value by given x in that domain?

Comment: Hi Weilory, the goal is to find a general equation. We have about 20-30 kinds of feedstock over a year, each giving different yields of various products, and we use a mix of 4-5 feedstock each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "*Multivariate Multiple Regression*" problem. Such a problem aims at modelling multiple *outputs/dependent variables* with the same set of *inputs/features/independent variables*. It is basically creating several regressors to model each output with the set of inputs and then combining them into one single model.

I would like to link an article for further information:
[https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/#:~:text=Multivariate%20Multiple%20Regression%20is%20the,single%20set%20of%20predictor%20variables.&text=And%20in%20fact%20that's%20pretty,variable%20separately%20on%20the%20predictors](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/#:%7E:text=Multivariate%20Multiple%20Regression%20is%20the,single%20set%20of%20predictor%20variables.&text=And%20in%20fact%20that%27s%20pretty,variable%20separately%20on%20the%20predictors).

Comment: Thank you. Seems tough for a beginner; I’ll think through it.

Comment: One approach I could suggest is building different models at first for different dependent variables.